# send an object in <div> dataset in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get a complete object in a div dataset and retrieve it in JavaScript.

This how my code looks like:

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  var config = {
    "user-id": "test001",
    "approach": true,
    "product-id": "testproduct1"
  }

  var x = document.createElement('iframe');
  x.setAttribute("id", "wrapper");
  x.setAttribute("srcdoc", '<script src="test.js"><\/script><div data-config="' + config + '" id="myid"></div>');
  document.getElementById('test').appendChild(x);
</script>
```

this is in the JavaScript file where I would like to get the data from data-config

```
const info = document.querySelector('#myid').dataset.data-config;
```

however, I get `[object object]` also tried the following, with the same result

```
var test = document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute("data-config");
```

to send a normal data attribute is working fine as such:

```
<div data-approach ='+ config.approach+' id="myid"></div>

var test = document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute("data-approach");
```

what results as `true` in my console.

how can I send the complete config so i don't need to take it apart one by one?

Comment: for a start ... think of `document.querySelector('#myid').dataset.data-config` as ` document.querySelector('#myid').dataset.data - config` secondly to access `data-config` from javascript it's `element.dataset.config` ... note the lack of `data-` - and finally `'+ config.approach+'` is the literal string `'+ config.approach+'`

Comment: You need to convert the object to a JSON string with `JSON.stringify(config)` and then use `JSON.parse()` when you extract it.

Comment: Also you need something like  `document.getElementById('wrapper').contentWindow.document.getElemenById("myId").dataset.config` but you are likely not allowed cross frame communication

Answer (score 2):

To set with JSON.stringify().

```
let data = {} // any referance data;

const info = document.querySelector('#myid').dataset.config = 
JSON.stringify(data);
```

To get the data with JSON.parse().

```
let data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#myid').dataset.config)
```

Comment: thanks I added your solution kinda in the code and works fine.  var info =  JSON.stringify(config); <div data-config='+ info +' id="myid"></div> and to retrieve: var test = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute("data-config"));